# How to use “$and” operator in Haskell MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, haskell

I am trying to use "$and" operator in Haskell mongoDB which is not working:

```
myFilter = do
   cursor <- MongoDB.find (MongoDB.select ["$and" =: [["field1" =: "test1"], ["field2" =: "test2"], ["field3" =: "test3"]]],  "db") 
   rest cursor
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there an error message? If so, what does it say? What did you expect? What did you get? What version of the package are you using?

Comment: @dfeuer:   Couldn't match expected type ‘Query’
                with actual type ‘(Collection -> aQueryOrSelection0, String)’

Comment: I want to query multiple fields with an "$and" operator. Is this syntax OK?

Comment: You should edit your question to add the full text of the error message in the question body. You should also include all relevant `import` lines in your posted code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unnecessary comma before "db" which is causing a type error.

Try this:

```
myFilter = do
   cursor <- MongoDB.find (MongoDB.select ["$and" =: [["field1" =: "test1"], ["field2" =: "test2"], ["field3" =: "test3"]]]  "db")
   rest cursor
```

Note:

- you don't really need to use "$and" because it is the default.
- where you specify "db" is the name of a collection.

Comment: it actually helped me do an $or query, I spent hours searching the net for it.